# C++ int array ends up with bad data in the middle

Tags: c++, arrays, corruption

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("adsf.txt");
int g [800];
for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 129; j++)
    {
        if((int)img.getPixel(i,j).a>111){
            myfile<<(j+353);
            myfile<<"\n";
            g[i]=j+353;
            break;
        }
    }
}
myfile.close();
```

This code results in a text file with these values, from lines 364-384:

481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481

These values are correct.

However, if I use a for loop to check the array after it's made, it results in these (and other, all of them in the middle of the file) being corrupted:

```
for (int h = 0; h < 800; h++)
{
    myfile<<g[h];
    myfile<<"\n";
}
myfile.close();
```

results in

481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
481
2004341180
1994199293
344
0
1994199326
1314101291
14019080
14019376
15809736
36

This corruption continues until line 489, when the file becomes accurate again.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `g[i]` is uninitialized when `(int)img.getPixel(i,j).a>111` is not met?

Comment: I'd start with `int g [800] = {};` to initialize all the values to 0.

Comment: @remyabel you have helped immensely thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you end up with fewer than 800 numbers in your file.

When the inner loop doesn't find a `j` for which the condition is satisfied, it a) doesn't output anything to the file, and b) leaves `g[i]` uninitialized, containing random garbage.